# Combining columns and calculating a total inventory qty

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, sum

This is my first post here so please help me correct my post if needed.  I'm working with a test inventory sheet that needs to calculate how my total inventory.  I need help with my 3rd `For` statement.  I'd like for it to calculate how much of each type of wood I have on hand.  For example, I would like the data to show that I have 4 pieces of oak, 3 mahogany, 15 cherry, and 11 birch.  Currently, the code is just adding the `QTY` column.

```
Sub Consolidate()
    Dim R As Range, c As Range
    Set R = Range("A1:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Columns("G:K").ClearContents
    R.Columns(4).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=Range("J1"), Unique:=True
    Range("G1").Resize(1, 5).Value = Range("A1:E1").Value

    For Each c In Range("G2:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row)
        c.Value = c.Row - 1
    Next c

    Range("H2:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row).Value = 1

    For Each c In Range("I2:I" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row)
        c.Value = Evaluate("INDEX(" & R.Columns(3).Address & ",MATCH(" & c.Offset(0, _
        1).Address & "," & R.Columns(4).Address & ",0))")
    Next c

    For Each c In Range("K2:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row)
        c.Value = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(" & R.Columns(4).Address & "=" & _
        c.Offset(0, -1).Address & ")," & R.Columns(2).Address & "," & _
        R.Columns(5).Address & ")")
        c.Value = c.Value
    Next c

    For Each c In Range("H2:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row)
        c.Value = Evaluate("SUM(--(" & R.Columns(4).Address & "=" & _
        c.Offset(0, -1).Address & ")," & R.Columns(2).Address & "," & ")")
        c.Value = c.Value
    Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Before VBA**

[image]

**After VBA**

[image]

Comment: Use SUMIF or a pivot table.

Comment: I plan on attaching the code to a button to generate the new table.  How do I use SUMIF if there is no table created until I run the other code?  For example can I use the SUMIF function inside VBA to generate values when the other portions of the table are created?

Comment: Presumably your other code spits out a table?

Comment: Yes, I edited the original post and added images.

Comment: You can easily obtain your desired results with a Pivot Table, or using Power Query

Comment: Is there a way I can accomplish this in VBA without Power Query, Pivot Tables, or sumIF?